# How can I prove this vector algebra statement

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

I am not sure this is true by the way.

Given two vectors in D-Dimensional space, A and B

is the square of the euclidean distance between them A.A + B.B - 2 A.B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is basically just [Cosine Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines):

\begin{align*}
\|\vec a - \vec b\|^2
&= (\vec a - \vec b) \cdot (\vec a - \vec b) \\
&= (\vec a \cdot \vec a) - (\vec a \cdot \vec b) - (\vec b \cdot \vec a) + (\vec b \cdot \vec b) \\
&= (\vec a \cdot \vec a) - (\vec a \cdot \vec b) - (\vec a \cdot \vec b) + (\vec b \cdot \vec b) \\
&= \vec a \cdot \vec a + \vec b \cdot \vec b - 2(\vec a \cdot \vec b) \\
\end{align*}